# How to calculate percentage of dataframe column in R with condition?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to find out how to calculate the percentage of a column based on a condition.

My table looks like this:

```
url    | call_count 
-------|-----------
bbc.com| 1
bbc.com| 1
bbc.com| 1
bbc.com| 1
ao.com | 0
ab.com | 2
```

I would like to group the table by the `url column` and calculate a new column called `"percent_calling"` - this is based on a condition whereby the **call_count column value is greater than 0** then calculate it as a percent of the whole column value - this is basically just % calling if the value is > 0 as >0 means they made a call.

I'm currently stuck on how to do this with dplyr the closest i have got is the following:

```
df %>% 
group_by(url) %>% 
summarise(percent_calling = sum(call_count)/nrow(df))
```

but as you can see i cannot add a condition i.e. call_count > 0

Comment: how does one do it whilst summarising the data? I am summarising more columns - e.g. count_of_urls which is just the sum of urls etc

Comment: what about `sum(call_count>0)/nrow(df))`

Comment: Use `summarise(percent_calling = sum(call_count>0)/n())` or just `summarise(percent_calling = mean(call_count>0))`. When you do `call_count>0` that returns a TRUE/FALSE value and when you use `sum()` or `mean()` TRUE values are treated as 1 and FALSE values become 0. This makes counting particular events pretty easy in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data:

```
df<-data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
               url = c("bbc.com","bbc.com",
                       "bbc.com","bbc.com","ao.com","ab.com"),
        call_count = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2)
)
```

Does the following work for you?

```
df%>%
  group_by(url)%>%
  summarise(sum_calling = sum(call_count))%>%
  mutate(percent_calling=sum_calling/sum(sum_calling)*100)%>%
  select(-sum_calling) # remove the sum if not required
```

```
 url     percent_calling
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 ab.com             33.3
2 ao.com              0  
3 bbc.com            66.7
```